# $\int \frac{1}{\cos x}dx$ by half angle substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int \frac{1}{\cos x}dx$$

By half angle I did:

$t = \tan\frac{x}{2}$

$$\cos x = 1-2\sin^2\frac{x}{2} = 1-2\frac{\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}{\cos^2\frac{x}{2}}\cos^2\frac{x}{2} = 1-2t^2\frac{1}{\sec^2\frac{x}{2}} =1 - \frac{1-2t^2}{t^2+1} = \frac{1-t^2}{t^2+1}$$

$$dt = \frac{1}{2}\sec^2\frac{x}{2}\implies dx = \frac{2}{1+t^2}dt$$

then $$\int\frac{1}{\cos x} = \int\frac{t^2+1}{1-t^2}\frac{2}{1+t^2}dt = \int\frac{2t^2+2}{1-(t^2)^2}dt$$

I know how to separate it in two integrals:

$$\int\frac{2t^2}{1-(t^2)^2}dt + \int \frac{2}{1-(t^2)^2}dt$$

The first one I know how to integrate, but not the last one. Could somebody help me? Also, Am I doing everything alrigt?

os: I know this integral is easier by $u$ substitution...

Comment: $\cos x=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$, not $\frac{1-t}{1+t^2}$.

Comment: I have not checked your work, but have you ever seen the inverse hyperbolic trigonometric identities when it comes to derivatives? Depending upon the limits of integration, the second integral looks a lot like $\tanh^{-1}\left(\theta\right)$ or $\coth^{-1}\left(\theta\right)$ ... http://math.info/Calculus/Derivatives_Hyp_InvHyp/

Comment: @ThomasAndrews sorry, I knew it but typed wrong. Aready corrected.

Comment: @bd1251252 I cannot use anything related to hyperbolic trig functions yet

Comment: Also why not cancel the two copies of $1+t^2$ right after you cnange from integrating $1/\cos x$?

Comment: Yes, $t^2+1=1+t^2$, because addition is commutative, so you can cancel. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cancel correctly, you end up with:

$$\int\frac{2\,dt}{1-t^2}$$

But: $$\frac{2}{1-t^2}=\frac{1}{1-t} + \frac{1}{1+t}$$

Comment: I ended up with $\ln|\frac{1+tan x/2}{1-tan x/2}|$ but the answer should be $\ln|sec x + tan x|$

Comment: It's true, the half-angle approach gives a different-seeming result. Are they actually different? Replace $\sec x +\tan x$ with their half-angle values and compute through to maybe see they are the same (up to a constant.)

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs, is  $\frac{1+\tan x/2}{1 - \tan x/2} = \sec x + \tan x$  not true?

Comment: $\frac{1+\tan u}{1-\tan u} =\frac{\cos u + \sin u}{\cos u-\sin u}$. Multipy numerator and denominator by $\cos u+\sin u$ to get $$\frac{\cos^2 u + 2\cos u\sin u + \sin^2 u}{\cos^2 u -\sin^2 u}=\frac{1+\sin(2u)}{\cos(2u)}=\sec(2u)+\tan(2u)$$

Comment: That is a general problem with using the half-angle formula, you end up with all those half-angles. :) If there is simpler substitution, you often get a very different-looking answer.